# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a chore app for my family and when I try adding a chore it throughs up this error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: chore [SQL: INSERT INTO chore (data, date, user_id)". Not quite sure I keep getting this error even though there is a table in my app called Chore. Any advice for a newbie? (I'm new to stack overflow too)

THIS IS MY model.py

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Chore(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    chores = db.relationship('Chore')
```

THIS IS MY views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, jsonify
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
from .models import Chore
from . import db
import json

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
  
  return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)

@views.route('/adhome', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def adhome():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        chore = request.form.get('chore')

        if len(chore) < 1:
            flash('Chore is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_chore = Chore(data=chore, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_chore)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Chore added!', category='success')

    return render_template("adhome.html", user=current_user)


@views.route('/delete-note', methods=['POST'])
def delete_note():
    note = json.loads(request.data)
    noteId = note['noteId']
    note = Chore.query.get(noteId)
    if note:
        if note.user_id == current_user.id:
            db.session.delete(note)
            db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({})
```

THIS IS THE HTML TEMPLATE PAGE adhome.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Chores{% endblock %} {% block content%}
<h1 align="center">Chores</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
   {% for chore in user.chore %}
   <li class="list-group-item">
      {{ chore.data }}
      <button type="button" class="close" onClick= "deleteNote({{ chore.id }})">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
<form method="POST">
   <textarea name="chore" id="chore" class="form-control"></textarea>
   <br />
   <div align="center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Chore</button>
   </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: program is complaining that table `chore` is not there, have you created this table?

Comment: Run your migrations to create your tables

Answer (score 0):

First idea: your class definitions don't contain assignments to **tablename**. I think that's necessary. That attribute must contain the table name as it's defined in the database.

If that doesn't help, you could show the code creating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, now I know lol. I just deleted my database and restarted I know this isn't a good idea for an actual project but I'll use your answers next time